# How to disable "allow fullscreen" messages in Chrome 56?

Tags: google-chrome

I read the [following article](http://www.itproportal.com/2014/06/11/how-get-rid-annoying-allow-fullscreen-messages-google-chrome-full-screen/) which told me to go to `Content settings > Fullscreen exceptions` and add the hostname patterns of the websites which I want to allow fullscreen acess to. However, it seems like it's no longer possible to do so in Chrome 56 because the fullscreen exceptions section no longer exists:

[image: Fullscreen exceptions section no longer exists in Chrome 56]

I wonder why was the fullscreen exceptions section removed from Chrome. It was really useful. Anyway, how do you disable these annoying "allow fullscreen" messages in Chrome 56?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a website which contain a video that asks for your permission to watch it full screen?

Comment: It's an online game called [Prismata](https://play.prismata.net/?w=1366&h=768) which requires fullscreen access with keyboard controls.

Comment: I don't think that this article would help you, what you're talking about is a Flash based game... The fullscreen permission does not handle Flash-based full screen permissions.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it for shock wave files?